# Hosting WCFweb service in IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am trying to host a WCF service written in .NET 3.5 in IIS 7.5 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine, without much luck. I also have Sharepoint 2010 installed on the machine. Here is my setup:

The physical path of the folder with .svc file is:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SmartSolution\Services\Services\ContainerManagementService.svc

I have created a web application in IIS for both Services folders.

Here is the config file for the WCF service:

```
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementServiceBehavior"
    name="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       name="ContainerManagementbasicHttpEndpoint" contract="MyNamespace.IContainer"/>                  
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ContainerManagementService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>      
   <behaviors>      
    <behavior name="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
</behaviors>
```

When I try to browse to: http://localhost/SmartSolution/Services/Services/ContainerManagementService.svc , I get the following error:
[image: Service Error message]

and if I click "Go back to site" I'm taken to my Sharepoint Central admin for some reason. How can I get the IIS service hosting working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have exposed the service on **port 8000** so you need to call it at `http://localhost:8000/ContainerManagementService`

Comment: No luck on port. How can you tell it's port 8000 that is being used, since it's not set in the config file? When I go to the "8000" URL, I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error.

Comment: Because you defined it as port 8000 in web.config: `<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ContainerManagementService" />`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately no luck on port 8000. After removing the host attribute, when I try to hit: http://localhost/SmartSolution/Services/Services/ContainerManagementService.svc, I get the same error page as the image above. I wonder if it's sharepoint related